# EOF when using pexpect and pxssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I'm trying to run the code in the *Interacting with SSH Through Pexpect* and *Brute Forcing SSH Passwords with Pxssh* sections from Chapter 2 of [Violent Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781597499576.do). Using both `child.expect()` and `pxssh` I get similar EOF errors.

Running these commands from the Python console:

```
import pexpect
connStr = "ssh root@127.0.0.1"
child = pexpect.spawn(connStr)
ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, "[P|p]assword:"])
```

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1316, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1330, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1401, in expect_loop
    raise EOF (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
EOF: End Of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Empty string style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x10180c550>
version: 2.4 ($Revision: 516 $)
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'root@127.0.0.1']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: TIMEOUT
    1: re.compile("Are you sure you want to continue connecting")
    2: re.compile("[P|p]assword:")
buffer (last 100 chars): 
before (last 100 chars): 
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 255 
flag_eof: True
pid: 12122
child_fd: 4
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

And running these commands, using `pxssh`:

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login("127.0.0.1", "root", "1234")
```

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pxssh.py", line
 196, in login
    i = self.expect(["(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting", original_prompt, "(?i)(?:pas
sword)|(?:passphrase for key)", "(?i)permission denied", "(?i)terminal type", TIMEOUT, "(?i)connectio
n closed by remote host"], timeout=login_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1316, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1330, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", li
ne 1401, in expect_loop
    raise EOF (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
EOF: End Of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Empty string style platform.
<pxssh.pxssh object at 0x1016bff90>
version: 2.4 ($Revision: 516 $)
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-q', '-l', 'root', '127.0.0.1']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting")
    1: re.compile("[#$]")
    2: re.compile("(?i)(?:password)|(?:passphrase for key)")
    3: re.compile("(?i)permission denied")
    4: re.compile("(?i)terminal type")
    5: TIMEOUT
    6: re.compile("(?i)connection closed by remote host")
buffer (last 100 chars): 
before (last 100 chars): 
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 12136
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

I get similar results when I substitute *127.0.0.1* with other hosts and try different username/password combinations.

The [pexpect documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/) suggests using `expect(pexpect.EOF)` to avoid generating the EOF exception. Indeed, when I do the following:

```
connStr = "ssh root@127.0.0.1"
child = pexpect.spawn(connStr)
print child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

The result is `0`.

But the following questions remain:

1. I'm confused by the book's syntax: `child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, "[P|p]assword:"])`. Why are we passing a list to `expect()`? What is this list supposed to contain?
2. How do I make use of `expect(pexpect.EOF)`, as the documentation instructs, when using pxssh?
3. Why does the code in the book not work properly? Has something changed in the pexpect library since the book's publication? Is it because I am on OS X?

I have Python 2.7 and pexpect 2.4 running on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: You may have added the ssh public key of the computer that is attempting to connect to the host. Are you sure when you attempt to connect you get the password prompt?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding #2:  Expecting EOF is a red herring here.  You -don't- expect EOF on login, you expect a password prompt on login.  pxssh kicks that error when it gets back EOF on login from ssh without getting a password prompt.  This can happen because it's using ssh -q to not get warnings, and you're getting a warning from ssh.  Take the ssh options it is using and run them yourself without the q:

/usr/bin/ssh -l root 127.0.0.1

In my case, I can get this error message when ssh is kicking out a known hosts violation due to the machine I am connecting to having its identity changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while trying to use `self.expect()` in `pxssh`. Changing the ssh options by removing the '-q' did not work for me.

I followed the instructions in [this](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html) site by adding pexpect.EOF as one of the inputs to `self.expect()`. This will make the script wait till the entire string is received before exiting when EOF is received:

```
i = self.expect(["(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting", original_prompt, "(?i)(?:password.*)|(?:passphrase for key)", "(?i)permission denied", "(?i)terminal type", pexpect.EOF, TIMEOUT, "(?i)connection closed by remote host"], timeout=login_timeout)
```

With this, it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time since this question was asked but it just took me quite a while to figure it out and maybe I can help the next people running into this issue.

I found out, that the issue was caused by a Timeout. The method `login()` has an argument with default value `login_timeout=10`. If you set this higher at like 20 instead of 10 then the original script from the book works fine. The resulting line is:

```
s.login(host, user, password, login_timeout=20)
```

Maybe next I should try and find out why my ssh login is that slow...